# Rewrite virtual servers directory into a top level domain

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I would like to rewrite directories of my RootDocument into thei'r own addresses.

For exaimple, I would like to be able to visit: `http://localhost/FOO` and be redirected to `http://FOO.dev`. Please note that the URL domain is static ass all subdirectory domains will have the same tol-level domain. I need to create a redirect within chunk of code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 127.0.0.1
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/var/www

    <Location />
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Location>

    <LocationMatch ^/[^.].+/$>
        RewriteEngine on

        /*
         I NEED A REWRITE HERE WHEN I REACH THE DIRECTORY LOCATION
         AS LOCATION IS ALREADY MATCHED, I'M NOT SURE HOW TO EXTRACT IT
        */
    </LocationMatch>

    <LocationMatch ^/[.].+/$>
        Options none
        AllowOverride none
        Require all denied
    </LocationMatch>
</VirtualHost>
```

Since I have already figured out how to get into directories I need to be at, how would I use my logic to extract and redirect me into correct place?

Comment: You need to setup name resolutions for those host names you make up. Without that you will send a request to either some other system out there or the request will fail due to an unknown host name.

Comment: the localhost is set by defautlt and the one i request is one which i need to take care of manually. i'm aware of it.

Comment: OK, if you say so... Next you need a redirection rule, not a `Location` directive if you actually want to redirect your client as you explain in the question.

Comment: I've used Location directive as I'm trying to preserve the main configurations. I'm having nested a nested virtual hosts, where lets say localhost is one, and all it's sub-directories are separate ones. Using Location directive allow me to retwrite my request correctly using NameBased host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a two-step-approach for this, since you have to handle two separate requests in the scenario you want to set up:

This is the rule to redirect clients to the new host name:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?(\w+)(/?.*)$ http://$1.dev$2 [R=301]
```

This is the rule inside that host to remap the request onto the internal folder in the file system again:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(\w+)\.dev$
RewriteCond /%1 -d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /%1/$1 [END]
```

Obviously the rewriting needs to be loaded and enabled for this.

In case you receive back a http status 500 ("internal server error") for the first request (the one to be redirected) chances are that you are using a very old version of the apache http server. In that case try replacing the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag...

Above rules will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or in dynamic configuration files. However you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only supported as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Seems like the first chunk of code I've placed inside my LocationRewrite and it redirects me to: http://usr.dev/local/var/www/FOO/. Was this something you expected?

Comment: I'm using mac os homebrew btw.

Comment: Such things do not belong inside a `Location` directive, they are to be applied globally.

Comment: Getting the absolute os path was something I've been betting as well. could be something worth mentioning.

Comment: ahh!!! ok, it works when placing it outside of LocationMatch. Did not need the second part as my sub-directories have already mapped their structure. I just need to skip the files on your match.

Comment: So you setup separate virtual hosts for each such host name? Not really a need for that, except if there are more separate settings required for those. It certainly works, though. So: all fine, have fun and a great weekend! ;-)